# use insert statement into a procedure !

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Can i use insert into tables in a procedure (on oracle) ? example:

```
procedure my_procedure (aa1 number ,aa2 number ) is 

begin 
  insert into lam_table values(aa1,aa2,null) ;(*ofcourse depending on the tables )
  ...
  ...
end ;
```

** note 
i tried it and it worked but there were a message in the bottom that said (successfully compiled not modified )

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can.  Just be aware of the difference between creating the procedure and executing it.  Once the procedure is created, you can execute it with:

```
begin
my_procedure(aa1, aa2);
end;
```

where aa1 and aa2 are the supplied values for the args.

Answer (score 1):

Just as dpbradley says. 
Also, any insert performed by your insert statement will only be visible in that session unless you do a
commit;